# Returning subclass in an interface method

Tags: java, methods, interface, subclass, return-type

I wanna make a linked list project in which I have created an interface and a class

CLASS:

```
  public class MainNode<T> implements Node<T>
    {
        public T data;
        public MainNode<T> next;
        public MainNode<T> nextIs()
        {
            return next;
        }
    }.           //all other methods are defined and work fine
```

INTERFACE:

```
public interface Node<T>
{
    public SUB_CLASS_RETURN_TYPE nextIs();
}         //all other methods are declared as needed
```

Problem: the problem is that what should be written in SUB_CLASS_RETURN_TYPE to return the object or reference of derived/sub class

Comment: Hint: please learn how to properly format source code within your question. Would make it much easier for us to actually understand your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is use generics

```
public interface Node<N extends Node<N>> {
    public N nextLs();
}

public class MainNode implements Node<MainNode> {
    @Override
    public MainNode nextls() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But on doing that, another method such as: `public T getdata();` don't work and show a compile error.

Comment: @SuhasSrivastava you need to add T as a generic as well.